# The projection of the force F=ai+bj, where a and b are non-zero constants, in the direction of the vector w=i+j

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, contest-math, vector-analysis, forcing

Now this is an easy projection question I know, but projections do my head in. 
I'm really not sure where to start, do I square to get the distance and then add vector w onto vector F?
Try not to downvote I normally give full working, but vectors are doo doo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the projection of a vector $\mathbf{u}$ onto a vector $\mathbf{v}$ is given by

$$
\text{proj}_{\mathbf{v}}\mathbf{u} 
= \frac{\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v}}{|\mathbf{v}|^2}\,\mathbf{v}\,,
$$

hence it follows that the length of the projection is

$$
\left|\text{proj}_{\mathbf{v}}\mathbf{u}\right| 
= \frac{\left|\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v}\right|}{\left|\mathbf{v}\right|}\,.
$$

---

In light of all this, being $\mathbf{u} = (a,\,b,\,0)$ and $\mathbf{v} = (1,\,1,\,0)$, it follows that:

$$
\text{proj}_{\mathbf{v}}\mathbf{u} 
= \frac{(a,\,b,\,0) \cdot (1,\,1,\,0)}{|(1,\,1,\,0)|^2}\,(1,\,1,\,0) 
= \frac{a + b + 0}{1^2 + 1^2 + 0^2}\,(1,\,1,\,0)
= \left(\frac{a + b}{2},\,\frac{a + b}{2}, \, 0\right),
$$

from which:

$$
\left|\text{proj}_{\mathbf{v}}\mathbf{u}\right| 
= \frac{\left|(a,\,b,\,0) \cdot (1,\,1,\,0)\right|}{\left|(1,\,1,\,0)\right|}
= \frac{\left|a + b + 0\right|}{\sqrt{1^2 + 1^2 + 0^2}} 
= \frac{\left|a + b\right|}{\sqrt{2}}\,.
$$

Comment: Because its a projection wouldn't it have to have the answer in terms of F or w?

Comment: Like ((a+b)/2)w or   F/a+b ? like with one of the vectors in the answer?